# Insert a list of objects java

Tags: java, performance, hibernate

I trying persist a many registers in database reading a file with many lines

I´m using a forech to read the list of objects wrapped in file

```
logs.stream().forEach(log -> save(log));

private LogData save(LogData log) {
    return repository.persist(log);
}
```

But the inserts are slow

Do i have a way to speed the inserts?

Comment: FYI, you can call `forEach()` without a stream: `logs.forEach(this::save)`

Comment: try using parralel stream

Comment: Try to start a transaction and execute the commit method at the end of that loop.  Don't forget the finally block for rollback execution :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your way take a long time because you persist element by element, so you go n time to the database, I would like to use [Batch processing](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html) instead to use one transaction instead of ***N transaction***, so the `persist` method can be :

```
public void persist(List<Logs> logs) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    logs.forEach(log -> session.save(log));// from the comment of @shmosel 
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Batch Insert, Google "Hibernate Batch Insert" or replace with whatever name of your ORM if it's not Hibernate.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_batch_processing.htm

Answer (score 0):

To insert at every line makes this program slowly, why dont you think to collect n lines, and insert n lines together at once.